# How to search a string in one pandas dataframe column as a substring in another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2`. I need to create a new column in `df1` by searching `df2['B']` to see if `df1['A']` is a substring of `df2['B']`. If there is a match return the value of `df2['A']` for the new column in `df1['B']`.

Below are sample dataframes

df1

```
      A                  B           
9.female.ceo.,ceo,       ?
9.female.ned.,ned,
9.female.ned.,chair,
2.female.ed.,ned,
2.female.ned.,ed,
9.female.chair.,ceo,
2.female.chair.,chair,
```

df2

```
     A                B
,ceo,ned,          2.male.chair.,ceo,ned,
,chair,ned,        2.male.ned.,chair,ned,  
,ned,              2.female.ed.,ned,
,ceo,chair,        6.female.ed.,ceo,chair,
,ed,ceo,           6.male.chair.,ed,ceo,
,ceo,chair,        9.female.ed.,ceo,chair,
,ceo,ned,          9.female.chair.,ceo,ned,
,chair,(in ft10),  9.male.ceo.,chair,(in ft10),
```

Merge wouldn't work in this case since `df1['A']` contains substring of `df2['B']`

Any help that points to the right direction will be very much appreciated.

**Expected results**

df1

```
      A                    B           
9.female.ceo.,ceo,       
9.female.ned.,ned,
9.female.ned.,chair,
2.female.ed.,ned,         ,ned,
2.female.ned.,ed,
9.female.chair.,ceo,      ,ceo,ned,
2.female.chair.,chair,
```

Comment: What is size of both DataFrames?

Comment: `df1` is 941 and `df2` is 66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create sets by split by `,` and match by `issubset`:

```
d = {k: set(v.split(',')) for k, v in df2.set_index('A')['B'].items()}
df1['B'] = [next(iter([k for k, v in d.items() if set(x.split(',')).issubset(v)]), '') 
                      for x in df1['A']]
print (df1)
                        A          B
0      9.female.ceo.,ceo,           
1      9.female.ned.,ned,           
2    9.female.ned.,chair,           
3       2.female.ed.,ned,      ,ned,
4       2.female.ned.,ed,           
5    9.female.chair.,ceo,  ,ceo,ned,
6  2.female.chair.,chair,
```

Solution with test by `in`:

```
d = df2.set_index('A')['B']
df1['B'] = [next(iter([k for k, v in d.items() if x in v]), '')  for x in df1['A']]
print (df1)
                        A          B
0      9.female.ceo.,ceo,           
1      9.female.ned.,ned,           
2    9.female.ned.,chair,           
3       2.female.ed.,ned,      ,ned,
4       2.female.ned.,ed,           
5    9.female.chair.,ceo,  ,ceo,ned,
6  2.female.chair.,chair,
```

Another solution with cross join by `merge` with test substrings by `in`:

```
df3 = df1.assign(tmp=1).merge(df2.assign(tmp=1), on='tmp', suffixes=('','_'))
df3 = df3.loc[[a in b for a, b in zip(df3['A'], df3['B_'])], ['A','A_']]

df = df1[['A']].merge(df3.rename(columns={'A_':'B'}), on='A', how='left')
print (df)
                        A          B
0      9.female.ceo.,ceo,        NaN
1      9.female.ned.,ned,        NaN
2    9.female.ned.,chair,        NaN
3       2.female.ed.,ned,      ,ned,
4       2.female.ned.,ed,        NaN
5    9.female.chair.,ceo,  ,ceo,ned,
6  2.female.chair.,chair,        NaN
```

Comment: once again thank you so much help. I always learn a lot from your solutions. Any recommendations on online materials or books to dive deep into pandas? Thanks!

Comment: @rescot - Hard question, I think [modern pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html#modern-pandas) is nice :)